# Sometimes putRecord doesn't return any response by AWS kinesis

Tags: python, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS boto python library.

I am hitting 10000 requests/sec from Jmeter to my web app which write data to kinesis stream.
I have used 16 Shards for Stream. when I stopped Jmeter I saw some of the records not written to stream. I have also my logs, but did not find any error.
This is my sample code

```
try:
       p_key = '{0}{1}'.format('partition_key',(1, 10000))

        # Connect to AWS Kinesis region
        kinesis_obj = kinesis.connect_to_region(region_name)

        # Put data on AWS Kinesis stream
        app.logger.debug(count++) 
        response = kinesis_obj.put_record(stream_name,record,p_key)
        app.logger.debug(count++)
        app.logger.debug(response)

except kinesis.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException, re_ex:
    write_log(record, re_ex)

except kinesis.exceptions.ResourceInUseException, inuse_ex:        
    write_log(record, inuse_ex)

except Exception, ex:
    write_log(record, ex)
```

When i print count here got 25000 requests.

```
response = kinesis_obj.put_record(stream_name,record,p_key)
```

and,
I got  24900 requests here.

100 missing records.

There is no response in `response` with no exception.

Comment: Did you track this down yet? I noticed you're calling `count++` both before and after you call `put_record`, which will not give an accurate count. Consider keeping a `success` count to clearly show records being inserted with no issues, and you'll need to show your consumer side code (the one that is showing a different count indicating missing records)